# MYSQL: select 3 rows starting at an ID, but go back to beginning if we reach the end

Tags: mysql

I need a MYSQL query that does the following:

select 3 rows starting at id n. If we've reached the end of the table, go back to the beginning.

For example, if we have 25 rows and we start at id 16, it should return 16, 17, and 18 (easy).

But if we start at id 24, it should return 24, 25, and 1.
if we start at 25, it should return 25, 1, and 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using a `UNION ALL`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM 
(
    (SELECT *
    FROM mytable
    WHERE id >= 16
    ORDER BY id
    LIMIT 3)

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT *
    FROM mytable
    ORDER BY id
    LIMIT 3)
) t
LIMIT 3
```